# I want to display the name which is start from 0 to 9

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I want to display the names which is start from 0 to 9. i do not to use reg_exp and like functions.

My data:

```
select * from emp2;
15326
25371
35371
48615
59718
69718
79718
89718
99718
05326
15326
25371
35371
48615
59718
69718
79718
89718
99718
a19716
b09414
d%5034
!5033
**5031
89718
39718
05326
a19716
b09414
d%5034
!5033
**5031
89718
39718
```

I used below query to fetch the records.

```
select * from emp2 where name between '0' and '9';

15326
25371
35371
48615
59718
69718
79718
89718
05326
15326
25371
35371
48615
59718
69718
79718
89718
89718
39718
05326
89718
39718
```

Result: As i am getting values form 0 to 8.. 9 is not fetching, why?

some more query i tried.

```
select * from emp2 where name between '+1' and '10';
05326
05326

select * from emp2 where name between '9' and '0';

no rows selected
```

why this statement is not fetching any of the records

MY expected result: I want to fetch the records whose name starts with 0 to 9.

Comment: "*i do not to use reg_exp function*" - Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from emp2 where name >= '0' and name < ':'
```

This statement would use an index on `name` column if it exists.

Answer (score 3):

The query you want is:

```
select *
from emp2
where substr(name, 1, 1) between '0' and '9';
```

You are misunderstanding `between` when applied to strings.  The expression:

```
name between '+1' and '10'
```

Is looking for names that start with a character ranging from a `'+'` to a `'1'`.  For digits, that would be those starting with `0` and `1`.

The expression:

```
name between '9' and '0'
```

is backwards, because the values for a between need to be in order.

The related expression:

```
name between '0' and '9'
```

comes close.  But it will miss something starting with `9` when there is another digit.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * 
FROM   emp2 
WHERE  SUBSTR(name,1,1)  BETWEEN 0 AND 9
```

Comment: Relying on implicit data type conversion is not such a good idea